# bluetooth InStream missing first character/splits string

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm receiving a string from stream input from bluetooth and the main issue is the characters aren't coming in as full strings. It for some reason reads the first character separately sometimes or the last few characters separately.

I've been searching for hours for a solution. I even tried sleep(), which is a hack that apparently works, but not all the time. I need it to work all the time.

Some people say bufferReader or dataInputStream is better?

```
bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                                     //if message is what we want
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                          // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
            sensorView0.setText(readMessage);
            if (readMessage.equals("Alarm")) {
                Intent buzz = new Intent(MainActivity.this, backgroundService.class);
                MainActivity.this.startService(buzz);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int bytes;

    // Keep looping to listen for received messages
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.available();
            while (bytes > 0) {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == handlerState) {
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
            //will keep combining the chars until end-of-line
            befEndLine = befEndLine + readMessage;
            // determine the end-of-line
            int endOfLineIndex = befEndLine.indexOf("\n");

            if (endOfLineIndex != -1) { //check if character is there if not skip
                String dataInPrint = befEndLine.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                received.setText(dataInPrint);
                //Clear the data held in string
                befEndLine = "";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Using TCP its pretty normal that data comes in in chunks. You yourself have to concatenate the strings until the complete command or message came in. So you have to know what is start and end of a message. What would be easy is that the sender sends lines so the user can read lines.

Comment: Thank you. I should have realized that it was coming in one character at a time instead of a string. On the microchip side, I added '\n' at the end for me to be able to know when full line is sent.